# Parse remote response from RestTemplate request

Tags: java, jaxb, resttemplate, spring-rest

I want to use this RestTemplate code to make remote POST requests. I tried this:

```
       public static void main(String[] args) {
    String token = "d778dh";
    URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://localhost:8080/bogus_rest_api/v1")
            .pathSegment(token)
            .build()
            .toUri();
    HttpEntity<PaymentTransaction> request = new HttpEntity<>(new PaymentTransaction());

    RestTemplate restClient = new RestTemplate();
    restClient.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor("petrov", "password2"));
    ResponseEntity<PaymentResponse> response = restClient.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST,
            request, PaymentResponse.class);
    PaymentResponse foo = response.getBody();
    System.out.println("!!! Calling Bogus Gateway " + foo.getTransactionId());

}
```

Object Send:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "payment_transaction")
public class PaymentTransaction {
    public enum Response {
        failed_response, successful_response
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "transaction_type")
    public String transactionType;
    @XmlElement(name = "transaction_response")
    public Response transactionResponse;
    @XmlElement(name = "response_code")
    public Integer responseCode;
    @XmlElement(name = "technical_message")
    public String technicalMessage;
    @XmlElement(name = "message")
    ......
}
```

Object Received:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "payment_response")
public class PaymentResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "transaction_type")
    public String transactionType;
    @XmlElement(name = "transaction_id")
    public String transactionId;
    @XmlElement(name = "amount")
    public Integer amount;
    @XmlElement(name = "currency")
    public String currency;
```

But get error probably because I have to configure proper object convert?

```
org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter@4f1bfe23

23:06:20.309 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Created POST request for "http://localhost:8080/bogus_rest_api/v1/d778dh"
23:06:20.534 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Setting request Accept header to [application/xml, text/xml, application/json, application/*+xml, application/*+json]
23:06:20.612 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Writing [org.datalis.plugin.rest.models.PaymentTransaction@747f281] using [org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter@1169afe1]
23:06:20.895 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - POST request for "http://localhost:8080/bogus_rest_api/v1/d778dh" resulted in 200 (OK)
23:06:20.896 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Reading [class org.datalis.plugin.rest.models.PaymentResponse] as "application/xml;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter@1169afe1]
!!! Calling Bogus Gateway null
```

Full Log: https://pastebin.com/WdML1yqH

I alway get Null as a response.
Can you propose how I can fix the issue?

Comment: Please explain what the problem is.

Comment: I get always Null for every value here  foo.getTransactionId().

Comment: You might want to actually explein the problem in your question.

Comment: Done, probably my code for request in wrong?

Comment: Try writing an isolated MCVE test which parses the XML you get using this `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` or whatever this thing uses. Also try to change the `transactionId` field to `transaction_id` (getters/setters as well). I have a feeling that `@XmlElement` annotations are not considered.

Comment: Do you see some issue into the code? Can you show me how to implement MCVE test which parses the XML you get using this MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter ?

Comment: No, not directly. My guess is that `@XmlElement` annotations are not considered. But I'm not quite familiar with Jackson XML mappers. This is why I suggested renaming the property first to see if it helps.

Comment: I can't tell you how to write a MCVE. I personally would check the source code to find out where and how XML gets unmarshalled. Then rewrite this code as an isolated test.